# Navigation Bar HTML not inline

Tags: html, navigationbar

With all the questions that people are asking about this topic are too complicated from that I have seen. I am trying to make a basic navigation bar to I can get used to how HTML works. Here is my code:

myFile.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>

</head>
<style>
ul  {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

li  {
        display: inline;
    }

a:link, a:visited {
      display: block;
      width: 120px;
      font-weight: bold;
      color: white;
      background-color: black;
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      }

a:hover, a:active {
      background-color: dark-grey;
      } 

body {
      background-image: url("fallout man and dog.jpg");
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-attachment: fixed;
      background-size: cover;
    }



</style>

<body>


    <ul>

        <li><a href="file:///E:/HTML folders/Fallout4Test/myFile.html">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="file:///E:/HTML folders/Fallout4Test/Videos.html">VIDEOS</a></li>

    </ul>

  <h1>This is the Heading</h1>

</body>

</html>

<!-- file:///C:/Users/tylersong55/Desktop/myFile.html -->
```

Videos.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>

</head>

<style>
ul {
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      }

li {
      display: inline;
      }


a:link, a:visited {
      display: block;
      width: 120px;
      font-weight: bold;
      color: white;
      background-color: black;
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      }

a:hover, a:active {
      background-color: dark-grey;
      }

body {
      background-image: url("fallout man and dog.jpg");
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-attachment: fixed;
      background-size: cover;
      }

h2 {
      background-color: black;
      color: white;

      }




</style>

<body>



    <ul>

        <li><a href="file:///E:/HTML folders/Fallout4Test/myFile.html">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="file:///E:/HTML folders/Fallout4Test/Videos.html">VIDEOS</a></li>

    </ul>

    <h2>Fallout 4 - Announcement Trailer</h2>

    <center><iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/XW7Of3g2JME" 
  frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></center>

  <h2>Fallout 4 - The Wanderer Trailer</h2>

  <center><iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/k3IlHBBGCIw" 
  frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></center>


</body>


</html>
```

I had it working at one point but I can't figure out why it won't become inline and then other times it will combine with the Header that I put right after it. Let me know if there is a better way to do this simply. I am self taught with what I am doing so far.

Thanks!

Comment: Try removing `display: block;` from the `a:link, a:visited` selector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you made the `a` element to `display:block`, it overrides the inline property from the `li` element.

I have put your code in a fiddle to show the results.

[Inline Nav Bar](http://jsfiddle.net/75pc4v9g/1/)

Comment: What could I do to make this look nicer? All I have so far is this sad looking bar that now sits horizontal but I can't get a good style on it. Is there another variable that I can use for the display part?

Comment: If this answers your question, please give it a checkmark. There are many ways to style it. I would recommend styling the <li> element with better padding and have a <nav><ul><li></li></ul></nav structure and style the <nav>

Answer (score 0):

Remove the Display:Block section and everything will move to inline, since you've set all of the li elements to inline.

To style your links as buttons, add the following to your CSS

```
ul a {
 padding: 20px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 text-decoration: none;
}
```

Hope this helps! I'm self taught too and pretty brand new to things.